# How to read html with jQuery in data in jQuery get method $.get

Tags: jquery

in jQuery statement:

```
    $.get(someurl, function (data) {
            ###
        });
```

I receiving something like:

```
<div class="somediv">john smith</div>
```

question is: how to jQuery read this data html $("div.somediv").text() in function response where ### is placed?

I need to read div text through div class name, because I can have a multiple divs with different class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if data == '<div class="somediv">john smith</div>'`

then this should just work

```
$(data).text()
```

if data has a bunch of other html you can always filter after making it a jQuery object

```
var text = $(data).filter('div.somediv').text();
```

if you need to do a selection later on, you can add it to the body like this

```
var $data = $(data)
$data.length && $(body).append($data.css('display','none'));
```

and later select like

```
$('div.somediv').text()
```

Comment: in that case you need to add it to the dom and then do another selection as @Francois has shown

Comment: I don't like your answer but it's appears true :)

Answer (score 0):

the `data` argument in the callback function contains whatever response `someurl` gave. Use `data` to access your HTML in the callback function, in this case.

To use jQuery filters and functions on it, you need to cast it to a jQuery object like this:

```
var obj = $(data);
```

Then you can just do `obj.text()` to get the text.

A shorthand version would be:

```
$(data).text();
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit. Edited.

Comment: allright, but how to read div.text accessing div by class name like $("div.somediv").text() ? I can have multiple divs with different classes

Comment: You can use any jQuery functions with `obj` as in my example above. `obj` is the parent element of the returned HTML. You need to edit your post with the _actual_ data you get returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "fake" div in your page, set its innerHTML with the data you receive, then get innerHTML of `somediv`.